# Date function returns NaN if variable given as input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nan

I am using google chrome and trying to build a messaging system. I need to display date/time of messages. I used date function but it is giving 'NaN' error. It works fine if I directly pass value,  but with a variable input. It fails. I searched for the answer but I am unable to identify problem. below is my code.

```js
  var d = jsarr[j];//  sets d = 1448702771436
            alert(d); //1448702771436
            var date = new Date(d); 
            alert(date); //invalid date
```

Comment: strange didnt get any errors runs like a charm

Comment: What's the type of `jsarr[j]` or `d`? Looks like it's not a number but a string.

Comment: I tried parsing 'd', with parseInt() and  now it works fine.  @Andreas I even tried parsing well before but somehow it was not working back then.  Thanks any ways

Comment: Post it as an answer to "close" this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried parsing 'd', with parseInt() and now it works fine. @Andreas I even tried parsing well before but somehow it was not working back then. Thanks any ways.
Might be because of uncleared cache, I hard refreshed. using ctrl + F5

```js
  var d = jsarr[i];   
        var s =  parseInt(d);//  changing type to Int 
          var date = new Date(s); // valid date
```